# how to write jenkins job config with SVN info by rest api

Tags: rest, svn, jenkins

I am using jenkins restapi to new a jenkins job , usually we do it like this:

```
from jenkinsapi.jenkins import Jenkins
J=Jenkins('http://localhsot:8080/')
J.create_job(jobName,JOB_CONFIG)
```

the question is how to write the JOB_CONFIG file with svn info which svn Authentication

now I am able to write the config without info of svn Authentication

the JOB_CONFIG as:
[image]

but I do not know where to add the svn Authentication (svn username&password)

could someone give me some help

many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an open bug about his issue

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-21617

Comment: thanks Efron anyway , when you new a job on jenkins web page ,you can fill your svn info then will pop up a form to fill svn name /password